# How to retain multiple subscriptions till their completion in Combine when we subscribe a single subscriber?

Tags: swift, combine

I have a single reducer in form of a `Subscriber`. The base class is like this:

```
class ResponseReducer<Input>: Subscriber {

    func receive(subscription: Subscription) {
        subscription.request(.unlimited)
    }
    
    func receive(completion: Subscribers.Completion<Error>) {
    }
    
    func receive(_ input: Input) -> Subscribers.Demand {
        return .unlimited
    }
}

let reducer = ResponseReducer<Response>()
```

And I subscribe it for network responses from different places the following way:

```
networkRequestPublisher
    .subscribe(reducer)
```

Multiple subscriptions may exist at the same time. And the underlying `Subscription` is not retained without extra effort in such cases. I get only `receive(subscription:)` call inside `ResponseReducer` as a result.

If it was only one subscription at a time, I would store a reference to it inside `ResponseReducer` and release it inside the `receive(completion:)` func. But I have multiple subscriptions and there is no reference to the completing subscription inside the `receive(completion:)` func when it is called.

Experimentally, I've found how to achieve what I need, but not sure it is a reliable solution:

```
networkRequestPublisher
    .handleEvents()
    .subscribe(reducer)
```

`.handleEvents()` operator does the job. It will also work if I replace `.handleEvents()` with `.receive(on:)` or `.print()` operators.

Can somebody explain, why the solution with `.handleEvents()` works?
And what would be the best way to solve this task?

Comment: @TusharSharma I have an opposite configuration: a single subscriber and multiple publishers.